# What's the oldest continuously-existing, still-open kosher restaurant?

Tags: history, restaurant

What's the oldest continuously-existing, still-open kosher restaurant?

Comment: Had you waited 12 seconds longer before posting this, it would have been the thousandth question.

Comment: Isaac, what lesson do we learn from the Nesiim?

Comment: :) Don't worry. Ain't no one gonna tell you all mi.yodeya has all the content it needs! Anyway, may your zerizut and generosity hasten the return of the Shechina to our midst.

Comment: @msh210 why is this on topic?

Comment: @YEZ arguably it's history of the practice of Judaism, [which is on-topic](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Feel free to cast a closure vote and/or bring the issue to [meta] or [chat].

Comment: @msh210 It's not asking how long we kept Kosher for.  If I asked, "How long have Jews been eating apples, which are Kosher" would that be on topic?  A restaurant is just an example of something Kosher.

Answer (score 2):

Fine & Schapiro Kosher Restaurant & Delicatessen
138 W. 72nd St., New York, NY 10023 
is open since 1927!

Comment: Any source for this?

Answer (score 2):

Hess in Yerushalayim has been a family sausage business since 1797, IIRC.

Comment: +1, although that doesn't sound like it was a restaurant all that time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly a restaurant, but Yonah Shimmel's Knish Bakery, according to their site [yonahschimmel.com](http://yonahschimmel.com), has been operating at the same location on East Houston Street in Manhatten, NY since 1910 selling kosher knishes, blintzes, and other goodies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a luncheonette on 16th Ave & 48th Street in Boro Park called Liberman's. It is open for over 40 years!

Answer (score -2):

It was Ratners in the Lower East Side until It closed but i think it was Non Kosher for a while too

Comment: not still open.

Comment: London's Blooms had been open 90 years, but recently closed!  http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/juliankossoff/100044765/blooms-restaurant-symbol-of-jewish-london-and-grumpy-waiters-shuts-down/

Comment: Please source this.